# WPF Window.ShowDialog() returns immediately on second call

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2013, modal-dialog

In my app I have the following code:

```
void ShowCaptchaWindow(Exception ex)
{
    var window = new CaptchaWindow(ex);
    window.Left = 800;
    window.Top = 500;
    window.ShowDialog();

    text = window.CaptchaText;
}
```

This code used to work fine before, but now I got problems with it. Strange thing is that I dont remember that I've changed anything.

When I call the function for the first time - everything is Ok, window is showing and function waits for it to close. But when I call this function for the second time - window doesnt displayed and I immediately goes to the next line.

Comment: Is `CaptchaWindow.DialogResult` property data-bound?

Comment: @Dennis nope. `CaptchaWindow.CaptchaText` is.

Comment: Such behavior is typical for the cases, when some code initializes `Window.DialogResult` property before calling `ShowDialog`. Consider looking at the `CaptchaWindow`'s code more attentively - may be, there's some condition, which evaluates to true at the second time, and sets `DialogResult`...

Comment: @Dennis nope, my code doing nothing with `Window.DialogResult` property. In both cases it is `null` before `window.ShowDialog();` called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I showed CaptchaWindow before showing application's MainWindow.